# How to change number of mapper with ORC files using tez?

Tags: hadoop, orc, apache-tez

I am trying to increase the number of map task. The file format is ORC and using TEZ for processing.

I am having a 2.8 gb files. Approximately 128 MB files and number of files is 29 approx.

Every time I execute 28 map task gets executed. I am trying to increase the map task count.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check these settings (see comments below):

```
set hive.tez.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;

set tez.grouping.min-size=16777216; -- files with smaller size will be combined if possible
set tez.grouping.max-size=67108864; -- (default is 1 Gb), files with bigger size will be splitted and more mappers started
```

Also you can control the number of mappers using this setting:

```
set mapreduce.job.maps=128; --better use grouping splits configuration (above) instead of this one because it is more flexible
```